# Issue with delay on loading homepage on a wordpress site hosted on IIS 7

Tags: php, javascript, windows, performance, wordpress

I have currently taken over the running of the following site:

http://www.claimsnational.co.uk.

However there seems to be some kind of issue with the loading of the homepage. It takes a good 11 seconds before the page even starts to load yet all other pages work fine.

For example:

http://www.claimsnational.co.uk/claim-type/personal-injury/

I am really at a loss as to what could be causing this as all other sites on the server are fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: What have you tried or looked into so far? Have you tried YSlow plugin for Chrome/Firefox, this will tell you if you have a lot of files/images to download. This could be one or a number of different things

Comment: PS - if you aren't already using it, add this plugin, it made a massive difference for my personal site performance. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: Yeah I've checked if it's an issue with the actual content but it doesn't seem to even begin to load for those first 10 seconds. It appears as if the browser is waiting for 10 seconds doing nothing before loading the homepage. Once this begins it's fairly quick though obviously needs some optimisation

Comment: One thing worth checking, if you can, go into phpmyadmin and see if that's slow too. Then this means the database is slowing it down. I had a problem just last week where one of my sites was really slow because another website on the same shared hosting platform was using up all resources.

Comment: Hmm phpmyadmin seems fine and there is only the wordpress site using it. It's strange as the only issue I am having is on the homepage all the other pages are loading fine.

Comment: There is about a 2 second delay on your "personal-injury" URL, which I would not consider OK. But yes, your home page is much worse. I don't think I can debug this in this forum but I'd bet on an underpowered or overloaded server.

Comment: Hmm the server is fairly powerful for our needs. Its an AMD Phenom(tm)II X6 2.80Ghz with 16GB Ram. I just checked the CPU usage when loading the site and the CPU and RAM usage are low. Most of the other sites it is serving are straight up HTML pages with no database backends or any asp or php usage.